# Connect to Redis (AWS) from Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: redis, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jedis, amazon-elasticache

What is the method to connect to Redis node in an Elasticache from an Elastic BeanStalk instance?
Would just the host-name (redis node endpoint) and port enough?
Or is there any other authentication I have to complete? I get this error when I try to connect to the node.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

Answer (score 1):

For our rails application we have in our configuration environment variables:

```
REDIS_URL=redis://ourname.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
REDIS_PROVIDER=REDIS_URL
```

and it works fine. Not sure specifically for your application, but this should resolve that.

Also, make sure that your redis node has the appropriate security group permissions. For example, if it is in sg-a and your Beanstalk nodes are in sg-b, make sure that sg-a has a tcp rule for 6379 for sg-b